# Selecting Specific Cell from Row in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Flexigrid with its onDoubleClick function. It returns the row as a variable when the dblclick event is fired (function (g,p))

I need to get the one cell in the row (g) that has the abbr attribute "TimeBillID". I can access the cells through g.cells[index].
The cell with the abbr may not always be the first one in the row.
I've tried g.cells.filter("[abbr='TimeBillID']") and g.cells.has("[abbr='TimeBillID']")

I know I can loop through each cell until i find the one that has the abbr, however I would prefer to not do that, as some of the tables that will be using this can have 20 or more cells per row.

Structure of the row:

```
<tr>
   <td abbr="TimeBillID"></td>
   <td></td>
..............
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Wont `$("td[abbr='TimeBillID']");` do?

Comment: No, that did not work, but $(g).children('td').filter('[abbr="TimeBillID"]'); did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to alexn the answer was $(g).children('td').filter('[abbr="TimeBillID"]');